# How can you have a template function in C# which match only a special subset of good types with no common interface?

Tags: c#, generics, type-safety

I would like to be able to write some C# code the non-repetetive way, using generics, like this:

```
   var t = someObject.CallMethod<T>();
```

or

```
   someObject.CallMethod(t);
```

where caller supplies the T/t they want to provide or consume.

And then, because I think static correctness checking of programs is awesome, I would like this to be a compiler error for some types but not others, based on how I built `someObject`. Generic type constraints look like they could help with this in their general shape... but unfortunately the pattern matching seems actually extremely limited in what it can do.

"Constraints can specify interfaces, base classes, or require a generic type to be a reference, value, or unmanaged type."

In this case the only base class I know `T` is going to have, is `object`, and I don't want to restrict whether is a reference, value, or unmanaged type. This leaves interfaces and.... yup, I don't think I really want to sprinkle interfaces, or provide interface wrappers, for every single type I use this method with (there's going to be a lot). Nor do I see a way to gradually add interfaces to an object?

Are there any tricks or workarounds which can be used to build an object of possibly 'dynamic' type (we need not write a class for it, the compiler will generate one), where you do have something like generic methods but that only work for a specific list of types that you've enabled when you constructed the object?

Comment: What `CallMethod` would expects to get ?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific: what types do you want to restrict it to, what are the criteria?

Comment: The ones which it's going to work for, because I added code to support them, which I know at compile time, but the compiler doesn't. :D

Comment: " because I added code to support them" ... then add an interface too. Or just write an extension method per type. C# doesn't do "duck typing". Though you *can* write an analyzer to throw errors that C# wouldn't normally generate.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Actually that also still wasn't exactly what I meant. I've revised the question. The key point is I don't really want to have to author custom types for this every time. I just want some kind of a reusable 'builder' pattern, which will let the compiler figure out, based on the way the object is built, which operations it is going to support, and then validate the code which comes later and consumes them.

Answer (score 1):

For now there is no pattern matching implemented in `where T : ...` clauses. The only way I think to accomplish this is to do sth. like:

```cs
public static void Caller()
{
    CallMethod("This is a string");
    CallMethod(1234);
}

public static void CallMethod<T>(T input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
         case string s:
              Console.WriteLine(s); 
              break;
         case int number:
              Console.WriteLine($"I am a int: {number}");
              break;
         default:
              throw new NotSupportedException("This type is not yet supported.");
    }
}
```

The downside is to have the Exception on runtime not as a compile(r) time error.
If you really want to have it at compile time, I think for now you do not come around and add more code to your class.

```cs
public static void Caller()
{
    CallMethod("This is a string");
    CallMethod(1234l); // compiler error will appear here because of long
    CallMethod(1234); 
}

public static void CallMethod(string s) => CallMethodImpl(s);
public static void CallMethod(int n) => CallMethodImpl(n);

private static void CallMethodImpl<T>(T input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
         case string s:
              Console.WriteLine(s); 
              break;
         case int number:
              Console.WriteLine($"I am an int: {number}");
              break;
         default:
              throw new NotSupportedException("This type is not yet supported.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's sort of in the spirit of what I want to do. I just wish it could be a compiler error instead of a runtime error because it is great when the compiler can prove that the code never throws.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith Yes would be great. Tested this code also in VS Preview with net8 and also found nothing which can match your requirements. At least I think you need to go with forward methods :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm still noodling on this trying to find an answer to my own question. People's thoughts are so far very helpful for reinforcing my belief that generic types are unfortunately not going to be able to achieve my dream solution of strong-typing in the context where I need it.(At least, not in C# 10!) I do see one other remaining slightly disappointing possibility is just go the other low-tech way - enumerate goodness, instead of trying to use generic constraints (since thats impossible).

i.e.

```
class TheClass
{
    public void TheMethod(GoodType1 t) => PrivateMethod<GoodType1>(t);
    public void TheMethod(GoodType2 t) => PrivateMethod<GoodType2>(t);
    private void PrivateMethod<T>(T t) => //...the 'generic' solution that really only works for some types...
}
```

This may be verbose, but at least gives me the main property I am trying to achieve: `TheClass.TheMethod(x)` will compile only if and only if x is a supported type.